# Storing complicated object by using JDBC transactions across multiple private method cause to overloaded code

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I'm using jdbc transactions as described here: [JDBC Transaction example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/) to store complicated object and its relations. For example to store a car I call `public` "general method" which need to store wheels, engine, car itself etc... It delegates these task to private methods, to which it pass connection. If at some step something went wrong thrown exception is being catch by public method and rollback is performed.

For example:

```
public boolean saveCar(Car car){
   Connection con = null;
   try{
        con = ....//get connection
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        storeCar(car, con);
        storeWheels(car, con);
        storeEngine(car, con);

        con.commit();
   } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       con.rollback();
   } finally {
      con.close();
   }

}


private void storeWheels(Car car, Connection con) throws Exception{
    String sql = "...";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.executeUpdate;
}
```

But I need to close `PreparedStatement` as well. It should be closed in a `finally` clause, so I have to write my private methods like this:

```
private void storeWheels(Car car, Connection con) throws Exception{
        String sql = "...";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{
           ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           ps.executeUpdate;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        } finally {
            ps.close();
        }

    }
```

Too many `try-catch` it makes my code error prone and overloaded. Also throwing Exception from catch block isn't look good. My question how can or is it possible to delegate these tasks as I described and avoid an unnecessary `try-catch` blocks in every private method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this beautiful library [DBUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) which has solved my problem:

```
private QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner();   //creating global runner object which used across all methods in my class

public boolean saveCar(Car car){
   Connection con = null;
   try{
        con = ....//get connection
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        storeCar(car, con);
        storeWheels(car, con);
        storeEngine(car, con);

        DbUtils.commitAndCloseQuietly(con);
   } catch(Exception e){
       DbUtils.rollbackAndCloseQuietly(con);
   } 

}


private void storeWheels(Car car, Connection con) throws Exception{
    String sql = "...";
    runner.update(connection, sql);  //all functionality encapsulated, performing update, closing statement, etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you store an `Engine` without storing a `Car` previously? The same question applies for every other component(s). If all those components must be created at the same time you create a `Car` you you should put the logic for those components all together inside `saveCar`. If not, your logic still is a little bit "obscure", since you are creating things separately — while you might be confused with an update operation, which, at some point can share the same code.

**NOTE:** I don't think it's a good idea to be passing a `Connection` object. Although there's nothing wrong with that but the inconvenience of having an unreleased resource at some point when your programs grows (if so). Look at it as "a good practice", not something you cannot do if it's well understandable/maintainable.

Comment: `Can you store an Engine without storing a Car previously?` Actually not, for example I have `many-to-many` relation table to store `wheels` against `car`, first I should store `car`, then `wheels`, and after I know ids of `car` and every `wheels` I can fill relation table above.

Comment: @Anatoly That's why makes sense to have everything as a single operation, rather than having then as single method calls that "look like" you are doing something for `car`, which may be true, but not for the operation you are doing right now